# How to store div content to DB?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

In my project,  sheet processing data will be append to a  timeTagDiv div(just like A and B are talking, and the content will show in the dialog).The new message send to dialog will append to timeTagDiv div. After that I want the whole timeTagDiv html content stores in the DB with ajax. Next time, these dialogue content will show in the div, So I konw what is going on.

Here is my js code:

```
var newCnt="<span class='dlgRsp'><label id='dlgRspTime'></label>&nbsp;<label id='dlgCharge'></label>&nbsp;accept sheet</span><br />";
$('#timeTagDiv').append(newCnt);
//var tmTgDvHtml=$('#timeTagDiv').innerHTML;
var tmTgDvHtml=document.getElementById("timeTagDiv").innerHTML;
var slcId = 2;
$.ajax({
        dataType:'json',
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_ajax_csc.php",
        data: {slcId:slcId,htmlCnt:tmTgDvHtml},
        success:function (data) 
        {}
       });
```

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="timeTag" id="timeTagDiv">
    <span class="dlgDate" id="firDlgDate"></span><br />
    <span class="dlgStTrl"><label id="dlgTime1"></label>&nbsp;<label id="dlgPrpsr"></label>&nbsp;create new sheet</span><br />
    <div id="dlgDiv1"></div><br />   
 </div>
```

Here is get_ajax_csc.php code:

```
  <?php
  include ("DB.php"); 
  if(isset($_POST['htmlCnt']))
  { 
   $sql="update IDC SET shProcess='".$_POST['htmlCnt']."' where id='".$_POST['slcId']."';";
   $sel = $conn->exec($sql); 
  }
   ?>
```

But unfortnately, these date of timeTagDiv can not be updated. I have tested that  tmTgDvHtml=document.getElementById("timeTagDiv").innerHTML can get the div html content.But i have no idea about that. Who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The div contect of htmlCnt should be formatted by stripslashes()

```
    $htcnt=stripslashes(".$_POST['htmlCnt'].");
```

It works fine.